# SAS: Continuously adding observations in a do loop

Tags: sas

I am working on a piece of code to take an array of dates and then out put an array of all dates that are within a given buffer of the dates within the original dates vector.

My plan is to use 2 nested do loops to loop through the original array of dates and each time add/subtract the buffer and then use data set to add these two observations to the original set.

I have been using the following code, but I end up in an infinite loop and SAS crashes.

```
%let buffer = 3;     
data dates_with_buffer; 
   do i = -1*&buffer. to &buffer.; 
      do j = 1 to 14; 
         set original_dates point = j; 
         output_dates = dates + &buffer.; 
         output; 
      end; 
   end; 
run;
```

Comment: could u pls provide an example of the input data set and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `point=` on a set statement, you need to include a `stop` statement as well to prevent an infinite loop. Try this:

```
%let buffer = 3;     
data dates_with_buffer; 
   do i = -1*&buffer. to &buffer.; 
      do j = 1 to 14; 
         set original_dates point = j; 
         output_dates = dates + &buffer.; 
         output; 
      end; 
   end; 
   stop;
run;
```